# Eclipse ADT cannot set conditional breakpoint on SDK sources: missing java Project context

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, conditional-breakpoint

I am trying to debug a simple Android app with Eclipse 3.7.1. I attachted the Android SDK sources so I can step through the code of the SDK also. I can set unconditional breakpoints on code of the SDK but not conditional breakpoints. I get the following error message if I try:

> Conditional Breakpoint Error
>
> Conditional breakpoint has compilation error(s).
>
> Reason:
>
> Unable to compile conditional breakpoint - missing java Project context

Conditional breakpoints on by own sources work, however.

The [only relevant search result on the topic I found](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/684459/)  suggests to convert the project containing the third party jar into a Java project. But I do not know how to do this for the Android SDK, i.e. how to add it as an Eclipse project at all. (Would that be even sensible?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix this error, create a new Java project for the Android library your project uses. Link the sources of the Android library delivered by the SDK to that project. Exclude everything (*), otherwise warning and error messages will flood your log! Attach the source code from that new project to the «android.jar» your project uses. That's it.

I wrote a more step-by-step solution [here](http://convales.blogspot.de/2012/05/eclipse-adt-conditional-breakpoint.html).

Comment: that worked but i am afraid i don't understand the root cause here. can you explain so i can create a bug report for this on the official bug tracker.