# How can I get Android Studio to debug into my SDK source code?

Tags: android, debugging, breakpoints

Since I can locate android sdk source with `ctrl+left click`, but when adding breakpoints to sdk source, it never stop at breakpoints.

So can I add breakpoints to sdk source?

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735870/eclipse-adt-cannot-set-conditional-breakpoint-on-sdk-sources-missing-java-proje

Comment: @HareshChhelana I don't think this works for android studio.

Comment: Try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486163/android-studio-how-to-debug-through-my-code-only