# Debuggging in the sdk of Android Studio

Tags: debugging, android-studio

In a java file in Android Studio I'm using a library named android.content.BroadcastReceiver. This library is part of the SDK-21 which source is given in Android Studio.

I have an issue with and Android device and I can't catch properly events when bluetooth headset device is connected.

I was trying to put some breakpoints in the BroadcastReceiver class, but it doesn't work in debug mode. It seems that the .class file of that object is not build up in my project and as a consequence I can't use properly the debug.

Is it possible to use debug mode for files that are part of the SDK?

Thanks

Comment: I found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309426/how-can-i-get-android-studio-to-debug-into-my-sdk-source-code

Comment: Try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486163/android-studio-how-to-debug-through-my-code-only